# How do I pin a manually installed executable to the Gnome3 panel

Tags: 11.10, gnome, gnome-panel

I installed a binary application 'Komodo Edit 6' on my ubuntu 11.10 laptop.  I'm using the gnome 3 desktop environment and was wondering how I can pin the application to my favorites list in the panel.

Right now I have the application installed in a Programs folder in my home directory.  And there is a single start up script that I use to run the program.

When I search for the application it returns the start-up script but when I click on it opens the file in gedit.

So I need to run from the command line.  This shows the application icon in the gnome panel but doesn't actually allow me to pin the app there, only shows the title of the app window.  I would like to just have an icon available to click and start the application.